# iptables: How to read this OPT string?

Tags: iptables, logging

I have a simple INPUT rule for iptables that logs any new connections to a logfile.
`--log-tcp-options` and `--log-ip-options` flags are both set and I get the appropriate `OPT` output.

One line of my log looks something like this:

> Nov 29 17:00:00 IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=x.x.x.x DST=x.x.x.x LEN=64
>   TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=37898 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57755 DPT=8888
>   WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 **OPT
>   (0204057D010303010101080A3E521D4D0000000004020000)**

I would like to understand how to interpret the `OPT` string (bold).

- Is there some documentation available on what it actually means?
- How could I make it human-readable?

Comment: "How could I make it human-readable" is too open-ended for this site. Now that you have the documentation, take a shot at making it human readable yourself and ask another question if you get stuck. We have no idea what tools you have available/are comfortable with, what format you consider acceptable, or where you want the transform to take place. You're both asking us to **BOTH** do your work for you and mind-read what work you want done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0204057D010303010101080A3E521D4D0000000004020000
From a sans.org study guide,
the first 2 bytes (0x0204) 04--is-length 02 means MSS flag
the next 2 bytes (0x057D) are the value for maximum size segment (MSS)
the next    byte (0x01)  is a no-op
the next 2 bytes (0x0303) indicate a windows scaling is enabled

the 3 bytes ("010101") are no-ops (AKA padding)
the 2 next bytes ("080a") flag a time stamp value
the 4 next bytes (("0x3E521D4D00000000") are date time 5 * 2 bytes
the 4 next bytes ("0402") sAck Ok

The master document:  ftp://ftp.ietf.org/iana/tcp-parameters/tcp-parameters.xml
Others:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tcpm-tcp-security-03
http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tcpm/current/msg03199.html

for humor! : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5841

Answer (score 3):

The RFC 791 defines the IPv4 protocol. In section 3.1, starting at page 15, there is an explanation about the `OPTIONS` field.

Source : [RFC 791](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt)

Comment: Thanks, could you maybe provide some example based on my output to make it human-readable?

Answer (score 0):

This is the options part of the TCP header.

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) for detailed information.

Comment: Hm, I already know about the OPT header itself and also what it does.
Could you elaborate on how I would parse such a sting and give an example based on my output?

Comment: BTW, Wikipedia is not an _credible and/or official source_.

Comment: Is this a statement of yours or has this been discussed on the stackexchange network?

Comment: well, if you dont believe what you read at wikipedia, then you can check the source (also referred to in the wiki section) here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793 

And no, i dont want to do your work, that not the point of this site. if you know how it works, take your time and parse the output yourself.